# Open txt file in Notepad from SharePoint

Tags: wss-3.0, office-integration

We are using WSS 3.0. We have a webpart that shows a list of documents in a document library.

If we click on a MS Word file with a doc extension, it opens in MS Word.

However, if we click on a text file with a txt extension, it opens in view mode in the browser.

Is there any way that we can get the txt file to open in notepad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, unless you do some local registry hacks on each machine that opens files with the content tyep text/plain in notepad instead of in the browser.

The reason that you can open Office documents is that SharePoint uses ActiveX to invoke the office application with its `ProgId`. Notepad does not have any COM ProgId.

You could make it so that .txt documents are opened in Word though.

Comment: Sigh... this is not solved from SPS 2003, huh?

Comment: See my answer below, seems to have been fixed in Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 there is an Edit-Control-Block menu option to "Edit Document" that opens txt files in Notepad (and log for that matter). Tested on Team Site Shared Documents and Windows 7 x64 / Windows Server 2012 clients. At least with Office 2013 it works as shown below.

[image: proof image]