# Open txt files in document library in an editor (notepad)

Tags: 2010, document-library

I added some txt files to a document library and would like to edit them in notepad.  However, I don't get this option.  Is there anyway do to this?

I realize this question is similar to: [Open txt file in Notepad from SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/open-txt-file-in-notepad-from-sharepoint), but I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Zork mentioned, there is no easy way to accomplish that. Having said that, if you have some development skills you could create a custom COM/ActiveX component like described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2010/05/13/using-custom-opendocuments-control-to-open-custom-file-types-in-sharepoint.aspx

Unfortunately this solution requires a client-side deployment.

Comment: That solution also would not work for notepad specifically due to the way notepad is built. It is certainly possible to use this type of solution, but it would definitely have to be something custom built for notepad. +1 for the cool link and associated code though!

Comment: Actually, it should work just fine by adding code to run notepad as a process and pass in the link to the text file. Did you try this?

Comment: thats exactly what im saying, you have to add specific code for notepad as opposed to the method in the link. Just trying to clarify it for anyone who would want to use that but not a clear understanding of what the code does

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. Looking through the code from the link I mentioned it actually contains everything required to open a text file with notepad.exe given the file extension .txt is associated with Windows Notepad on the client computer. All you need to do on the server is using txt instead of pdf in docicons.xml and deploy the component on your client computer.

Comment: huh guess im flat out wrong then! thanks for checking

Answer (score 1):

You could have SharePoint as a network drive and open the document as though it were a file on your system.

Unfortunately there's no good way of opening it directly to notepad from SharePoint.

Comment: Were you able to solve the "open with Notepad" issue by adding the document library as a network location?  When I add a SharePoint site to my network location I still have the same issue: can't open non-MS Office documents.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue but noted that files with .log extensions opened up with notepad. A simple change of the file extension from .txt to .log in explorer view in the document library "fixed" the issue. This is not really scaleable but is annoying in that the behaviour is not consistent between non Office apps.

I have looked at trying to create a simple workflow to change the extensions but no luck as designer only seems to allow you to update properties of the document.
I'll keep trying.

Comment: I don't think that changing the file extension is the best way to handle this. If anything it would just cause end user confusion.

Answer (score -1):

It works for both txt and log files in SharePoint 2010 with Windows 7 clients. Must have been fixed at some point.