# Can a SharePoint Document library be mounted like a traditional drive?

Tags: document-library

Am using Windows XP and SharePoint 2007 (relics, I know!).

I have added my SharePoint sites via *My Network Places :: Add a network place* and these sites show up in *My Network Places* under the *Local Network* heading.  I can browse the Document Libraries and add/remove files and -- when it comes to MS Office documents, at least -- I can open/edit files easily enough.

However, it doesn't behave *entirely* like a traditional drive ... and I'm wondering: is there anyway to map a Document Library so that it *will* behave like a normal folder?

Behavior I am seeing is:

1. Can't drag a file directly from the Document Library Explorer window into an email.
2. Can't edit non-MS Office documents (they will just open in Internet Explorer, for example: a basic text document loses the right-click 'edit' option and a double click opens IE instead of Notepad).
3. Can't save a file to the Document Library from a non-MS Office piece of software (for example, if I open WordPad, browse to my network places and open my SharePoint site I cannot save the file).

Reading questions like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33128/open-txt-files-in-document-library-in-an-editor-notepad/33130#33130) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/open-txt-file-in-notepad-from-sharepoint) make me wonder if this is even possible.  On other web servers, I would use SSH to mount a folder (or FTP or something similar).

Is there a way to do this with SharePoint?

Comment: Can you try simple Map drive option in Windows XP? Use URL of the document library like `http://<server>/Docs`.. check [Can I Map a Document Library as a Mapped Drive?](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/can-i-map-a-document-library-as-a-mapped-drive.aspx)

Comment: My XP session is limited ... I don't have that "Map Drive option" ... is a work machine in a managed environment.  Oh well.