# How to open Text files in SharePoint 2013 in their native program i.e Notepad

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

`*.txt` files are opening in browser for all users. Is there a fix on the server level so that `*.txt` files are prompted to open in Notepad?

The default association for such file types on the system is Notepad already.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a dated answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/open-txt-file-in-notepad-from-sharepoint) stating that this is not possible. However you could try the following:

- In your SharePoint's Central Administration, Confirm that **Browser File Handling** is enabled at **Manage Web Applications** > **General Settings**.
- Then, on your site collection's root, confirm that the site collection feature for **Open Documents in Client Applications by Default** is enabled.
- Finally in your local Windows, confirm that the default program used to open .txt files is Notepad.

After confirming these, open Notepad in Windows. Go File > Open, and in the file selection window write the address to a path where you have a .txt-file hosted in SharePoint (e.g. `http://site/Documents/file.txt`). After you have the .txt-file opened, you can close your Notepad, and restart your browser. By doing the file opening once this way, .txt-files *may* now be prompted to be opened with a client program (i.e. Notepad) when they are opened in SharePoint. I'd expect that the best results are achieved by using IE.

This was suggested in here: https://sharepointmaestra-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/37/Opening--txt-Files-in-NotePad

Other than that I don't think there are many options for opening .txt-files in client programs directly through SharePoint. You can always open the file hosted in SharePoint by pasting its full URL to the file explorer's address bar though, but that's still quite manual approach.

Comment: You would need to accomplish this via MIME types in IIS. There are no SharePoint settings that would impact this behavior.